# Order Total on Cart not showing price with TAX

Tags: cart, tax, magento-2.1.3

Using Magento 2.1.3 - Adding a product to the cart, then doing to the cart page the Grand Total shows up without taken into account Tax, however on the main area were the cart list the products they will have the Tax price there.

Shipping Origin has been set and shopping Cart display settings is set to:

```
Display Prices: Including Tax
Display Subtotal: Including Tax
Display Shipping Amount: Including Tax
Include Tax in Order Total: Yes
Display Full Tax Summary: Yes
Display Zero Tax Subtotal: No
```

Is there anyway to get Tax to correctly display on the Grand Total on Cart

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get reflect
go: stores/configuration/sales/tax/ then calculation settings and change the values by your desired position

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Tried all the settings in the calculation area but still giving the same as above.